# Value to pass to WIN32 API Function MonitorFromWindow as DWORD

Tags: excel, vba, windows, winapi, dll

The function calling the API in vba:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MonitorFromWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal HWND As Long, ByVal DWORD As Long) As HMONITOR
```

I have tried to pass 0 as dword,

```
Debug.Print MonitorFromWindow(Application.HWND, 0)
```

hoping to get MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST but the function returns nothing. What are the values of the below constants?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow

[image]

For instance other API's list the value underneath the constant:

[image]

Comment: Quick way - google for "private const MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST" (it's 2), Slow way - download the Platform SDK and look in the .h header file the documentation will name.

Comment: Also, if you're using `PtrSafe` then you should really be passing `HWND` as a `LongPtr` not `Long`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These constants are defined in the SDK include file "WinUser.h" as

```
#define MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL       0x00000000
#define MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY    0x00000001
#define MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST    0x00000002
```